# How to call Linux kernel driver functions from a userspace program?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

**How can I write a C program (in userspace) to call functions that are part of a kernel driver? If it's not possible to do directly, how else do I do it?**

CONTEXT: I am trying to use the PWM pins of my single-board computer (Intel NUC DE3815TYBE) so that I can control fans. A linux driver called pwm_lpss allows control of these pins (driver developed by Intel, source code [here](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/pwm/pwm-lpss.c)). I have verified that this driver is installed by using the `lsmod` command. Here is the driver information after typing `modinfo pwm_lpss`:

```
filename:       /lib/modules/3.19.0-25-generic/kernel/drivers/pwm/pwm-lpss.ko
license:        GPL v2
author:         Mika Westerberg <mika.westerberg@linux.intel.com>
description:    PWM driver for Intel LPSS
srcversion:     44AA14AF3E2F96C813770A8
depends:
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.19.0-25-generic SMP mod_unload modversions
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        6A:AA:11:D1:8C:2D:3A:40:B1:B4:DB:E5:BF:8A:D6:56:DD:F5:18:38
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
```

So I know where the driver module is (the `pwm-lpss.ko` file) and I have the source code which I know has a function in it called `pwm_lpss_config()` that I'd like to use. How do I call the function from my userspace C program? How would I go about #including it? Or is this not possible to do from userspace?

Unfortunately Intel has provided zero documentation for how to use this driver. I thought drivers normally map their functionality to some user-accessible file. I was able to find some PWM-related files after some digging, but I haven't been able to find a file that looks like it can set PWM duty cycle/frequency.

Comment: It's a standard driver, so, documentation is in kernel for ages: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/pwm.txt

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a standard Linux [PWM](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/pwm.txt) driver, so no special documentation is necessary.

Check the `/sys/class/pwm/` directory. (`/sys` is the interface the kernel provides for access to its data structures. It just looks and acts like a filesystem.) You should have something like `/sys/class/pwm/pwmchip0/`. Each such directory corresponds to a PWM chip.

The directory will have the following entries. You may need superuser privileges to access these (as you wouldn't want everybody to mess with them):

- `npwm`: Read this to find out how many PWM channels this chip has.
- `export`: Write a channel number (0 to whatever-the-number-in-`npwm`-1) to make that channel available via this sysfs interface
- `unexport`: Write a channel number to remove the channel from sysfs interface control

Each PWM channel exported to be used via the sysfs interface will show up as a subdirectory named `pwmN`, where `N` is the channel number. Here, you can read and write to entries

- `period`: Total period (off + on) in nanoseconds.
- `duty_cycle`: On time in nanoseconds. Must be less than period.
- `polarity`: If the chip supports reversing the signal polarity, you can write `inversed` here to invert the polarity; `normal` is the default/normal polarity.
- `enable`: `1` if enabled, `0` if disabled.

When reading or writing to these entries, no special locking is necessary. The kernel will receive all data in one `write()`, and return all data in one `read()` operation. When a `write()` succeeds, the kernel has applied the setting.

Comment: Thank you! I knew I was missing something. I couldn't find documentation because I was searching for "pwm_lpss" instead of just doing a google search for "linux pwm". I feel pretty dumb; I didn't realize they were implementing a standard driver.

Answer (score 1):

some `ioctl` ? `The ioctl() function manipulates the underlying device parameters of special files.`

Along the lines

```
fd = open("/dev/pwm0", O_RDONLY); // put whatever device you've got
if (ioctl(fd, STATUSGET, &status) == -1) // magic constant should be set
    ....
} else {
    ....
}
```

Comment: Wrong, this driver, well PWM framework, has sysfs interface.